# Modify columns with PostgreSQL (beginner)

Tags: postgresql, calculated-columns

I would like to transform a database.

I am starting from this…

```
    path ; cost; sexe
    42-60 ; 12; male
    42-60; 5; female
    42-61; 3.59; male
    42-62; 13.85; male
    42-62; 2.96; female
```

…and would like to transform it to the following…

```
path; male; female
42-60 ; 12; 5;
42-61; 3.59; 0
42-62; 13.85; 2.96
```

I know I have to use `array_agg`, but I'm not sure how to use it to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

```
create temporary table test as
select * from (values ('42-60', 12, 'male'),
                      ('42-60', 5, 'female'),
                      ('42-61', 3.59, 'male'),
                      ('42-61', 13.85, 'male'),
                      ('42-62', 2.96, 'female')) as t(path, cost, sex);

select path,
       sum(case sex when 'male' then cost else 0 end) as male,
       sum(case sex when 'female' then cost else 0 end) as female
from test group by path;
```

Is this what you are looking for?